# How can I inject the twig engine service inside a twig templating helper?

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

My bunde needs to render some twig templates internally. So I look the [Twig documentation](http://components.symfony-project.org/templating/trunk/book/02-Templating) and I think the twig engine is the solution.

Unfortunately, the service in which I need to inject the twig engine is a twig templating helper used in a `TwigExtension`. So I obtain a `ServiceCircularReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the others who want to do the same thing, the solution proposed on the symfony github repository is to inject the service container and request twig engine just before I need to render the template. The service container can be inject into any services without obtain a `ServiceCircularReferenceException`